# VB.NET System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Tags: vb.net

Hi any idea why i'm getting this error message?
The original piece of code i'm using which works normally.. However, I decided I wanted to add more values to the code hoping it would work.. but I keep getting this error message. And for project a module was made.

(Module Code)

```
 Module Structure_Units
    Structure UnitsStruct
        Public ValueOne As String
        Public ValueTwo As String
        Public ValueThree As String
        Public ValueFour As String
        Public ValueFive As String
        Public ValueSix As String
        Public Sub New(rawValue As String)
            Dim Values() As String = Split(rawValue, ",")
            ValueOne = Values(0)
            ValueTwo = Values(1)
            ValueThree = Values(2)
            ValueFour = Values(3)
            ValueFive = Values(4)
            ValueSix = Values(5)
        End Sub
    End Structure
End Module
```

(Original Code)

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections

Public Class Structures

    Dim Units(3) As UnitsStruct

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Label5.Text = Units(ListBox1.SelectedIndex).ValueOne
        Label6.Text = Units(ListBox1.SelectedIndex).ValueThree
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Justi\Desktop\SDD Major Project\NLR.txt"
        Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(path)
        Dim Index As Integer = -1
        While Index < 3
            Index += 1
            Dim Current As String = reader.ReadLine
            Dim fields() As String = Current.Split(";"c)

            Units(Index).ValueOne = fields(0)
            Units(Index).ValueTwo = fields(1)
            Units(Index).ValueThree = fields(2)

            ListBox1.Items.Add(Units(Index).ValueTwo)
            Label1.Text = Units(Index).ValueOne
            Label2.Text = Units(Index).ValueTwo
            Label3.Text = Units(Index).ValueThree
        End While
    End Sub
```

(New Code I attempted to remake)

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections

Public Class frmLightRail

    Dim Units(7) As UnitsStruct

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Label5.Text = Units(ListBox1.SelectedIndex).ValueOne
        Label6.Text = Units(ListBox1.SelectedIndex).ValueThree
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Justi\Desktop\SDD Major Project\NLR.txt"
        Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(path)
        Dim Index As Integer = -1
        While Index < 7
            Index += 1
            Dim Current As String = reader.ReadLine
            Dim fields() As String = Current.Split(";"c)

            Units(Index).ValueOne = fields(0)
            Units(Index).ValueTwo = fields(1)
            Units(Index).ValueThree = fields(2)
            Units(Index).ValueFour = fields(3)
            Units(Index).ValueFive = fields(4)
            Units(Index).ValueSix = fields(5)

            ListBox1.Items.Add(Units(Index).ValueTwo)
            Label1.Text = Units(Index).ValueOne
            Label2.Text = Units(Index).ValueTwo
            Label3.Text = Units(Index).ValueThree
            Label4.Text = Units(Index).ValueFour
            Label5.Text = Units(Index).ValueFive
            Label6.Text = Units(Index).ValueSix
        End While
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the point of overwriting the labels' Text property on each iteration of the While loop? You have a constructor for the structure where you can pass all the Value fields in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it could go wrong if the code tries to read a line from the `NLR.txt` input file that contains less than 6 fields (separated by semicolons, not commas).

The code is pretty messy. I have the impression that the "original" code is not complete as well. Was the `UnitsStruct` part of the original code, or have you added/modified that code as well? Why does the original program only read three lines from the input file and your new code seven lines? Why does the original code split each line into three fields and your new code into six fields?

I guess you should analyze your input file in some more detail and share that information with us by adding it to your question. How many lines does (or can) the input file actually contain? In how many fields should each line actually be split? Does each line have a fixed number of fields, or can the number of fields be different per line?

Answer (score 0):

I made the `Structure` into a `Class` and made the fields into Properties. I also added a `.ToString` method so the `ListBox` would know what to display.

My test.txt file looks like this.

```
Mary,had,a,little,lamb,it's
The,quick,brown,fox,jumped,over
Now,is,the,time,for,all
We,the,people,of,the,United
```

Streams need to be disposed. So, let's simplify by using the System.IO `File` Class. `.ReadAllLines` returns an array of lines in the file. We loop through each line, passing it to the constructor of the class which sets all the properties. Then the new `UnitClass` is added to the list, all fleshed out with its properties.

Create a `BindingSource` and set its `DataSource` to the list. The `BindingSource` becomes the `DataSource` for the `ListBox`. The same `BindingSource` is used for each of the labels. This will syn the ListBox and the Labels. As items in the `ListBox` are selected the proper values appear in each `Label`.

```
Class UnitClass
    Public Property ValueOne As String
    Public Property ValueTwo As String
    Public Property ValueThree As String
    Public Property ValueFour As String
    Public Property ValueFive As String
    Public Property ValueSix As String
    Public Sub New(rawValue As String)
        Dim Values() As String = Split(rawValue, ",")
        ValueOne = Values(0)
        ValueTwo = Values(1)
        ValueThree = Values(2)
        ValueFour = Values(3)
        ValueFive = Values(4)
        ValueSix = Values(5)
    End Sub
    'The list box will call .ToString on the UnitClass instance to determin what to display
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return ValueTwo
    End Function
End Class

Private UnitBinding As BindingSource
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lst As New List(Of UnitClass)
    Dim path As String = "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\test.txt"
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    For Each line In lines
        Dim unit As New UnitClass(line)
        lst.Add(unit)
    Next
    UnitBinding = New BindingSource
    UnitBinding.DataSource = lst
    ListBox1.DataSource = UnitBinding
    Label1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", UnitBinding, "ValueOne"))
    Label2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", UnitBinding, "ValueTwo"))
    Label3.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", UnitBinding, "ValueThree"))
    Label4.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", UnitBinding, "ValueFour"))
    Label5.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", UnitBinding, "ValueFive"))
    Label6.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", UnitBinding, "ValueSix"))
End Sub
```